# Material css collapsible header alignment issue

Tags: html, css, materialize

I have a [codePen link here](https://codepen.io/DirtyBit/pen/XyBPxo)

What I want is the last button (3 dots) to be aligned as the text in the left side.

This is my code

```
<ul class="collapsible popout">
    <li class="fade">
        <div class="collapsible-header bold">
            <div>
                <a class=" context-button waves-effect waves-light menuButton" >
                    <i class="material-icons grey-text text-darken-1">more_vert</i>
                </a>

                <span class="right light grey-text text-darken-3">Test1</span>
                <span class="rightMargin">Test2</span>
                <span class="green-text rightMargin" style="word-wrap: break-word;">test4</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapsible-body">
            Hello
        </div>
    <li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons);
.rightMargin {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.menuButton {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
position: absolute;
right: 10px; //to align the button to right side.
```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/dholakiyaankit/pen/gQjdVm)

Comment: I want the button (3 dots) to be placed to the right corner. What you have shown is left aligned.

Comment: @Roshan Your question was quite confusing, I have edited my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.menuButton {
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 21px;
    right: 12px;
    }
```